# So I'm trying to convert some .cbr files to .cbz

Tags: windows-10, command-line, 7-zip, archiving

And I've been trying to reverse engineer it through looking at the old files I've got. What I've got thusfar is

> ren *.cbr *.rar
>
> for .rar %%X in (*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x "%%X\" "%%X.rar"
>
> for /d %%X in (*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%X.zip" "%%X\"
>
> ren *.zip *.cbz
>
> echo

The result being that... only the first rename operation works. Meaning the CBR files are renamed to .rar files, which is what it's supposed to do.

(For those interested and not in the know, .cbr files are literally .rar files, literally archived the same way. The extension is meant to differentiate .rar files containing mass numbers of images for comic archive readers. .cbz is the same for .zip, and .cb7 for .7z)

Comment: Give this a try after the `REN` command `for %%F in ("C:\Folder\*.rar") do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x "%%~fF" -o"%%~pF\"`... If that works let me know and I'll help with the rest and write up an answer with more explanation, etc. Tag me back so I get the notification with `@` followed by my username so I get notified. Also explain what are trying to archive in the zip files (files in one folder, all top level folders only, etc.).